# Issue with XML parsing using Commons JXPath

Tags: xpath, domparser, jxpath

I'm trying to parse a XML using Apache Commons JXPath. But for some reason, its not able to identify the child nodes after the xml is being parsed. Here's the sample code :

```
private static void processUrl(String seed){
    String test = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?><feed xmlns=\"http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom\" xmlns:media=\"http://search.yahoo.com/mrss/\" xmlns:openSearch=\"http://a9.com/-/spec/opensearchrss/1.0/\" xmlns:gd=\"http://schemas.google.com/g/2005\" xmlns:yt=\"http://gdata.youtube.com/schemas/2007\"><id>http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos</id><logo>http://www.youtube.com/img/pic_youtubelogo_123x63.gif</logo><link rel=\"alternate\" type=\"text/html\" href=\"http://www.youtube.com\"/><author><name>YouTube</name><uri>http://www.youtube.com/</uri></author><generator version=\"2.1\" uri=\"http://gdata.youtube.com\">YouTube data API</generator><openSearch:totalResults>144</openSearch:totalResults><entry><id>http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/P1lDDu9L5YQ</id><published>2010-09-20T17:41:38.000Z</published><updated>2011-09-18T22:15:38.000Z</updated><category scheme=\"http://schemas.google.com/g/2005#kind\" term=\"http://gdata.youtube.com/schemas/2007#video\"/><link rel=\"alternate\" type=\"text/html\" href=\"http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=P1lDDu9L5YQ&amp;feature=youtube_gdata\"/></entry></feed>";
    Document doc = null;
    try{
        DocumentBuilder builder = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance().newDocumentBuilder();
        ByteArrayInputStream bais = new ByteArrayInputStream(test.toString().getBytes("UTF8"));
        doc = builder.parse(bais);
        bais.close();

        JXPathContext ctx = JXPathContext.newContext(doc);
        List entryNodes = ctx.selectNodes("/feed/entry");
        System.out.println("number of threadNodes " + entryNodes.size());
        int totalThreads = 0;
        for (Object each : entryNodes) {
            totalThreads++;
            Node eachEntryNode = (Node) each;
            JXPathContext msgCtx = JXPathContext.newContext(eachEntryNode);
            String title = (String) msgCtx.getValue("title");
        }
    }catch (Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

I've used JXPath earlier and never had any issues. I debugged the document object,it doesn't seemed to have the child node () for . All I'm able to see is the root element. I also tried DOMParser without any luck.

```
DOMParser parser = new DOMParser();
        Document doc = (Document) parser.parseXML(new ByteArrayInputStream(sb0.toString().getBytes("UTF-8")));
```

I'll appreciate if someone can provide pointers to this isuse.

Comment: One thing I found is if I remove the attributes from <feed xmlns=\"http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom\" xmlns:media=\"http://search.yahoo.com/mrss/\" xmlns:openSearch=\"http://a9.com/-/spec/opensearchrss/1.0/\" xmlns:gd=\"http://schemas.google.com/g/2005\" xmlns:yt=\"http://gdata.youtube.com/schemas/2007\"> and simply make it <feed>, then the JXPath is able to resolve the nodelist. Unfortunately,this is a feed which I can't change, any reason or workaround to handle this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This issue has to do with how JXPath handles default namespaces, which closely follows the [XPath 1.0](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/#namespace-nodes) specification. This also explains why it worked after you removed the default namespace `http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom`. In order to get it to work with the default namespace you can do the following:

```
JXPathContext ctx = JXPathContext.newContext(doc.getDocumentElement());
// Register the default namespace, giving it a prefix of your choice
ctx.registerNamespace("myfeed", "http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom");

// Now query for entry elements using the registered prefix
List entryNodes = ctx.selectNodes("myfeed:entry");
```

For more information on the issue see the following links.

http://markmail.org/message/7iqw4bjrkwerbh46

[Make jxpath namespace aware](http://www.waltercedric.com/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=1315&catid=130&Itemid=332)

Comment: Thanks a ton, worked like a charm.Thanks for the pointers to the docs, got a better understanding on the namespace issue.